# How to convert bytes stored inside a buffer to a variable?

Tags: c

So I'm reading from a file descriptor which contains an `int` variable in its raw byte format.

So I'm doing:

```
char buffer[sizeof(int)];
ssize_t sizeOfFile = read(sock_fd, buffer, sizeof(int));

int extractedInt = ???;
```

How can I convert that buffer to an integer? I was thinking of memcpy but was wondering if there are better ways.

Comment: You could read directly to an int.

Comment: Or define `union` with `char buffer[sizeof(int)]` and `int value` members. Load file into `buffer`, then use int `value`.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons - Use this family of functions for communicating over the network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read directly an integer

```
int extractedInt;
ssize_t sizeOfFile = read(sock_fd, &extractedInt, sizeof(int));
```

`read` will read the size of an int bytes, and store them into `extractedInt`.

If your `int` is actually a string in a file you want to convert to an `int`, the procedure is a bit different.

```
#define SIZE 20

char buffer[SIZE]; // ensure there is enough space for a string containing an integer
ssize_t sizeOfFile = read(sock_fd, buffer, SIZE);

int extractedInt = atoi(buffer);  // convert string to integer
```

Comment: It should be noted this requires the incoming byte order to match the local machine‘s byte order. (Big endian is commonly used in network protocols.) Also, this is fine when we know the next four bytes contain an `int`. That is what OP asked for, but sometimes you will read an entire packet or other message and analyze it before figuring out where in it there is an `int` that you want. In this case, the `memcpy` solution is useful. A complete answer could include that.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess from your code that you're reading from the network. This is then not portable to just read a `int` from the buffer, in your network protocol you chose a certain endianness but you cannot expect that all the platforms where your program will run to have the same, so it will lead to bad convertions.
And other proposed solutions of asking `read` to return an `int` will lead to the same problem.

So in your case, I can only advice to iterate through your array and compute the integer by progressively placing the bytes at the right place depending on the endianness of the platform.

You can detect the endianness of the build target platform by using the macro `__BYTE_ORDER__`in GCC.

There is an example for network data that is big endian:

```
// construct an `int` with the bytes in the given buffer
// considering the buffer contains the representation
// of an int in big endian
int buffer_to_int(char* buffer, int buffer_size) {
    int result = 0;
    int i;
    char sign = buffer[0] & 0x80;
    char * res_bytes = (char*)&result; // this pointer allows to access the int bytes
    int offset = sizeof(int) - buffer_size;

    if( sign != 0 )
        sign = 0xFF;

    if( offset < 0 ) {
        // not representable with a `int` type
        // we chose here to return the closest representable value
        if( sign == 0 ) { //positive
            return INT_MAX;
        } else {
            return INT_MIN;
        }
    }

#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
    for(i=0; i<buffer_size; i++) {
        res_bytes[i] = buffer[buffer_size-i-1]; // invert the bytes
    }

    for(i=0; i<offset; i++){
        res_bytes[buffer_size+i] = sign;
    }
#else
    // same endianness, so simply copy bytes using memcpy
    memcpy(&result + offset, buffer, buffer_size);

    for(i=0; i<offset; i++){
        res_bytes[i] = sign;
    }
#endif

    return result;
}
```